# GrammarCells not found by Standalone IDE build script

Tags: mps

What’s the right way to add a third-party dependency to the build file?

I’m trying to build a standalone IDE for a language that uses *grammarcells*  as dependency, but I get an error saying that the dependency cannot be found during the build process.

```
cannot find used language in dependencies: com.mbeddr.mpsutil.grammarcells
```

The error only occurs for the Build Solution, in the language solution, I can use grammarcells without issues.

Grammarcells is loaded into my IDE
[image]

It is also in my Solution for the Standalone IDE
[image]

And model
[image]

However I get the same error every time I try to build the project

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the  problem, I did the following two steps:

First, I added `de.itemis.mps.grammarcells.build` to your build model.
[image]

Second, I added `de.itemis.mps.extensions` to the list of dependencies in my build script
[image]

Finally, Re-Build :)

Thanks to @arimer from the MPS slack channel for helping me to solve the problem.